# Incompressible countable Total-ordering implies well-ordering i

Tags: combinatorics, logic, order-theory, ordinals

A totally-ordered set (S,<) is incompressible if $(S,<) \cong (T,<)$ and $S \supseteq T$ implies $S = T$.

Is it true that if $S$ is incompressible countable and totally-ordered then $S$ is well-ordered?

Comment: You're supposed to try the problem yourself, not ask on Math SE. Also, you missed out the "cushioned" condition as in Brian's answer.

Comment: So S must actually be finite.  After all, if $(S,<)$ is incompressible, then $(S,>)$ is incompressible and hence well-ordered too.  (Or you can just see directly that a well-ordering of order type greater than $\omega$ can't be incompressible.)

Comment: @MitchellSpector: He mis-stated the question. The correct question is stated in the answer below, which is clearly because Brian M. Scott was familiar with the original question.

Comment: Thanks, @user21820 -- that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Say that a linear order $\langle X,\le\rangle$ is *cushioned* iff every order-preserving injection $f:X\to X$ has the property that $x\le f(x)$ for each $x\in X$. Let $\langle X,\le\rangle$ be an incompressible linear order. If $X$ is not cushioned, there are an order-preserving injection $f:X\to X$ and an $a\in X$ such that $f(a)<a$. Define

$$g:X\to X:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
f(x),&\text{if }x\le a\\
x,&\text{if }x>a\;;
\end{cases}$$

then $g$ is an order-isomorphism from $X$ to $g[X]$. But $a\notin g[X]$, so $g[X]\subsetneqq X$, contradicting the incompressibility of $X$. Thus, $X$ must be cushioned. It follows from Theorem $3.0$ of Brian M. Scott, [*A characterization of well-orders*](https://eudml.org/doc/211238), Fundamenta Mathematicæ, $\mathbf{111 (1)}$, $71$-$76$, [MR0607921 (82i:06001)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=607921), that $X$ is a well-order.